# Condition for counting distinct rows in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL database with an ID column. This is not a key of the table and several rows can have the same ID.

I don't really know SQL but I already figured out how to obtain the number of distinct IDs:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM mytable;
```

Now I want to count only those IDs which appear more than 2 times in the table.

So if the ID column contains the values

```
 3 4 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7
```

the query should return 2.

I have no idea how to do this. I hope someone can help me!

Btw, my table contains a huge number of rows. So if there are several possibilities I would also be happy to know which solution is the most efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM (
    SELECT ID FROM mytable
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(ID) > 2) p
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(ids)
FROM 
      (SELECT 
           COUNT(ID)AS ids 
       FROM 
           mytable 
       GROUP BY 
           ID
       HAVING 
           ids>2
       )AS tbl1
```

Comment: Try it: you get the error *Every derived table must have its own alias*. Add a dummy alias at the end and it will be correct

Comment: You're still missing `GROUP BY id`... How can you use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`? Check it out...

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from 
    (select count(id) as cnt,id from mytable group by id) da 
where da.cnt>2
```

The inner query will give you how many elements does each id have. And the outer query will filter this.

Answer (score 0):

Updated :

```
SELECT count(ID) 
FROM (
SELECT ID FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(ID) > 2
) p
```

should do what you need